# Cannot convert System.Threading.Task.Tasks to System.Func<System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

My code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PageAsyncTask t = new PageAsyncTask(cancelPayPalAsync());

    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(t);

    // Execute the register asynchronous task.
    Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();
}
```

Which calls:

```
public async Task cancelPayPalAsync()
{
//Leaving blank for security reasons        
}
```

This line here:  `PageAsyncTask t = new PageAsyncTask(cancelPayPalAsync());` more specifically `cancelPayPalAsync` is spitting out the error

> Cannot convert System.Threading.Task.Tasks to
> System.Func<System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>

I'm aiming to make the page wait for my code to execute before loading, using my Async method. I don't know how to deal with this problem, and I don't see any solutions on the internet/stackoverflow.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `new PageAsyncTask(cancelPayPalAsync)`

Comment: Why are you calling ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks yourself? It gets called automatically by the framework. Check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.executeregisteredasynctasks?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

As Guru Stron pointed out in a comment, adding the () to `PageAsyncTask t = new PageAsyncTask(cancelPayPalAsync());` makes it refer to a function that returns a task rather than the task itself.

`PageAsyncTask t = new PageAsyncTask(cancelPayPalAsync);` will work.